# Does mlogit from statsmodel expect a wide format?

Tags: statsmodels, mlogit

Discrete Choice Analysis with Python.
Generally, there are two formats for representing regression data:

1. long format
2. wide format

Long format features a row for each potential option, plus a Y column with either 0 or 1 based on the choice. Wide format has only one line per person (survey respondent), and the Y comprehends all the features that are selected and the X comprehends all the product alternatives.

**Example Long**

```
person answer   Y ~ x1     x2    
1      1        0   green  large 
1      1        1   red    large
1      2        1   green  small
...
```

**Example Wide**

```
y1     y2     ~ x11     x12    x21     x22    
green  large    green  large   red    large
green  small    green  small   red    small
...
```

1. Is my description correct?
2. does statsmodel mlogit use the wide format here described?

Comment: It uses neither. I think the examples are not supported. See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548375/multinomial-conditional-logit-regression-why-statsmodel-fails-on-mlogit-package

Comment: you write: "the parameters differ across choices but not the explanatory variables"
what are the parameters? does that mean that the mlogit function is not supporting my usecase of choice based conjoint? ( oh my god its all so complicated. )