# python alternative for `mlogit`

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, mlogit

`R` has the `mlogit` library, which allows to model "discrete choice models". It accommodates both alternative (choice) specific and/or individual (chooser) specific variables. This means, e.g., if all variables are choice related, that we can limit the `beta` coefficients to be the same across different choices.

`python` has the `statsmodels` library. The `MNLogit` allows to model a "baseline-category logit model". But here it will estimate different `beta`'s per choice. Is there any way to restrict this? Or to mix both choice and chooser specific variables?

Comment: *Sigh*... Such trigger-happy people in this forum. This is not a recommendation. This is "how to do something".

Comment: I didn't vote on it, and I don't have an answer for your question, but ... your title _sounds_ strongly like it's asking for a python package that does what R's `mlogit` does, which is "asking for software libraries". Not saying it's right, but it's one interpretation. (Sorry I don't have anything more constructive to add ...)

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat if you want this to reopen, add some code (both for r and python), show the results and highlight the difference, and then ask how to do what you're after in python. As it stands, the question should remain closed, even if it does not ask for a recommendation, it lacks a [mre].

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566565/333700 answer still applies. statsmodels does not have this model